# Why does my extention String not put the Chinese character in Atom with script package?

Tags: ruby, string, encode, atom-editor

My code is below:

```
class String
      def self.nick_name
      p "小s "
    end
end

String.nick_name
```

Result:

> "\u5C0Fs "
>   [Finished in 0.269s]

I expect the result to be `小s`.

I attach the screenshoot here:

[image]

---

**Attention**

I am using Atom editor and the script package.

Comment: It **is** a chinese character, represented as ruby/atom wanted. Execute the code in normal shell to get the hieroglyph itself printed out.

Comment: What's the name of the atom package you're using to run the script?

Comment: Also, it is Atom-related question, that has nothing to do with ruby itself. Voted to close.

Comment: @cobaltsoda, I am using the script package, and `command` + `i`, to run it.

Comment: I'd suggest you raise an issue on the [`script` GitHub page](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues); that's a better place to get support for your question.

Comment: @cobaltsoda, ok, thank you ,shoul I delete my post?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the ruby's problem, it is the script package's issue.